# Eclipse needs to be closed to save settings

Tags: eclipse, jsp, ide

I'm making a web app in eclipse, when i make the changes they are not reflecting on my next run.

I'm doing the below.

```
save changes-> Stop Server-> start server-> run program
```

but the error appeared before is up again.

I use Kepler 32-bit. please let me know how i can fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your app after saving. If you don't have auto build on then your changes will not be reflected also make sure you publish to server too. Although Since you are restarting the server that may not be needed.
[image]
[image]